# Is $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ a bounded variation on $[0,1]$? I think yes.

Tags: real-analysis

This is (part of) a problem from Kolmogorov Fomin's book. It says that

> $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x^\alpha \sin \frac{1}{x^\beta}, & \text{if } 0<x\leq 1 \\ 0, & \text{if } x=0 \end{cases} $$    is of bounded
>   variation if $\alpha > \beta$ but not if $\alpha \leq  \beta$

Now, taking $\alpha = \beta = -1$ gives the function $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and this function does not go too much on the *y-* axis (by just looking at its graph) hence it must be of bounded variation, in my opinion.

What do I miss?

Comment: What you might be missing is that $f(0) = 0$ but $\sin(x)/x \to 1$ for $x\to 0$ so this function is not continious (dont know if that has to be true though).

Comment: @Winther, I know that. But still it seems to be a very bounded variation function, isn't it? Its move on the y-axis is still bounded.

Comment: Yes. I totally agree that $\sin(x)/x$ is a bounded variation on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Perhaps there is a restriction that $\alpha,\beta \geq 0$?

Comment: I'm sure the author in this theorem have assumed $\alpha > 0$. Otherwise the function is not bounded close to $x=0$.

Comment: $\sin (x) / x$ is decreasing on $(0,1]$. Hence BV. 

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%20x%20/x%20,%200%3Cx%3C1

Comment: @ThePortakal : As Winther rightly says the function $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ is unbounded close to $x=0$. Therefore the function  $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ on $[0,1]$ is not of bounded variation.